# Why the binomial theorem doesn't work at $ k=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

For an expansion $(1+x)^k$, you get $0$ when you let $k=0$ and apply the Binomial Theorem. However, the answer from my book is $1$. I'm either missing something or my book isn't telling me when the theorem does and doesn't work. Please clear this up for me!

Answer (score 6):

It works:

$$(1+x)^0=\sum_{k=0}^0\binom0k1^kx^{0-k}=\binom001^0x^0=1\cdot1\cdot1=1\;.$$

I suspect that what you’re missing is the fact that $\binom00=1$.

Comment: We also conveniently assume that if $x=0$, then $0^0=1$

Comment: @imranfat: Indeed. In most settings, and certainly in combinatorial settings, that’s the only definition that makes sense.

Comment: You mean if x=-1,so 1+x=0.

Comment: @user254665: Or perhaps **imranfat** meant that $x^0=1$ when $x=0$.